# Array en LocalStorage se actualiza pero no se suma al Array pasado

Tags: javascript, html, array, local-storage, guardar

estoy haciendo un proyecto donde tengo una facturación que se guarda en el LocalStorage (la facturación se hace mediante unos input HTML).
Cuando le doy a REGISTRAR FACTURA los datos se guardan correctamente, pero si actualizo la factura desaparece(correcto) y cuando intento agregar otra factura en vez de sumarse los datos a la factura pasada se actualiza el Array.

Por ejemplo:

localStorage cuando REGISTRO FACTURA = key: Factura, value: 5325, 54334, 12345

Si actualizo la pagina y REGISTRO OTRA FACTURA con otros datos, estos datos (5325, 54334, 12345) desaparecen y aparecen los nuevos.
Todo esto en JavaScript. Muchas gracias.

HTML:

```js
const RegistrarFactura = () => {
    var CogerTabla = document.getElementById("tablaFacturacion");
    var nRows = CogerTabla.rows.length;
    var valores = [];
    for(i=1;i<=nRows;i++){
        var tRows = CogerTabla.rows[i]; //numero lineas
        var nColumns = tRows.cells.length; //numero columnas
        var ultimoTd = tRows.cells[nColumns-1]; //ultimo td
        var valor = ultimoTd.innerHTML; //valor ultimo td
        valores.push(valor);

        var total = [];
        total.push(valores);
        localStorage.setItem("Valores", total); 
    }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tablaFacturacion" bordercolor="#9c9c9c" style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px;">
        <caption>FACTURA PARA EL CLIENTE</caption>
        <tr style="background: #9c9c9c;" >
            <td style="border-top-left-radius: 7px">Nombre cliente</td>
            <td>Producto</td>
            <td>Precio producto</td>
            <td>Cantidad producto</td>
            <td>Descuento</td>
            <td>ITBIS</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
            <td style="border-top-right-radius: 7px">Precio Total</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Puedes publicar tu código? Ya que asi es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Perfecto, perdón por no haber subido el código pero me inscribí ayer , en un rato subo el código HTML y JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en que `localStorage.setItem(...)` sobreescribe el valor previo. Por lo tanto es necesario que consigas el valor anterior en la llave que quieras, lo proceses y luego lo guardes nuevamente.

Te recomiendo también que, como `localStorage` guarda solo texto y estás guardando un arreglo en esta, uses la funciones nativas de JavaScript `JSON.stringify(...)` para convertir tu arreglo a string antes de dárselo a la localStorage y `JSON.parse(...)` para convertir el string que viene de la localStorage a array.

Un ejemplo sería algo como:

```
var stringArreglo = localStorage.getItem(“Valores”)
var arreglo = JSON.parse(stringArreglo)
// ir cambiando el arreglo
for(...){
    // se consigue un nuevo array para añadir
    var nuevosValores = [123, 456]
    arreglo = arreglo.concat(nuevosValores)
}
var nuevoArregloString = JSON.stringify(arreglo)
localStorage.setItem(“Valores”, nuevoArregloString)
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias!, aún no lo he logrado pero creo que tu código me podría ayudar